# Appium: Unable to locate an element on MainActivity after logging in for second time

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

I'm new with Appium. I'm currently testing an app and facing issues when trying to locate a mobile element that belongs to MainActivity second time I log in.

**My app(tracker) works as follows:**

As it stands, a pin code is provided to the user for logging in. When user logs in for first time has to set up the app (on Main activity page) enabling a VPN and app usage permissions. Once this is set up the tracker is up and running and user is presented with  a new page where can stop/start the tracker ( it belongs to MainActivity page too). Easy. Second time that user logs in or starts the tracker no set up is required and user is directly presented with stop/start tracker page (belonging to main activity page)

**SCENARIO 1**

The test I'm doing works fine if user starts from scratch the app:
* Log in
* Enable VPN
* Enable app usage permissions
* Check user is presented with start/Stop tracker stage

```
@Test(enabled = true, priority=1)
public void basicTitleTest() throws java.lang.InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
    LoginActivity loginActivity = new LoginActivity(driver);
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity(driver);
    AndroidActivity androidActivity = new AndroidActivity(driver);

    loginActivity.registerApp("******");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    String current = driver.currentActivity();      
    System.out.println(current);
    mainActivity.enableVPN();

    mainActivity.clickOnOpenSettings();
    androidActivity.enableSettings();
    androidActivity.navigateBackToWakoopaApp();
    mainActivity.verifyAppIsReady();

}
```

**SCENARIO 2**

Whereas when I log for second time, it can't locate the mobile elements belonging to start/Stop tracker stage
* Log in
* Check user is presented with start/Stop tracker stage

```
@Test(enabled = true, priority=1)
public void basicTitleTest() throws java.lang.InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
    LoginActivity loginActivity = new LoginActivity(driver);
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity(driver);

    String context = driver.getContext();
    System.out.println(context);
    loginActivity.registerApp("*******");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

    Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
    int size = contextNames.size();
    System.out.println(size);

    mainActivity.verifyAppIsReady();


}
```

Where:

```
public void verifyAppIsReady ()  throws InterruptedException { 

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
    assertTrue(stopTrackerButton.isDisplayed());

    }
```

stopTrackerbutton has an unique id, it can only be located in the first scenario.
Any ideas?

*Error log*
FAILED: basicTitleTest

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by
>   this strategy: Locator map: 
>   - native content: "By.chained({By.id: toggleStopStart})" 
>   - html content: "by id or name "stopTrackerButton""   at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:102)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:61)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b598166c.isDisplayed()
>     at Pages.MainActivity.verifyAppIsReady(MainActivity.java:72)    at
>   Tests.TestLaura2.basicTitleTest(TestLaura2.java:69)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) Caused
>   by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction@4925f4f5
>   (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:303)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.waitFor(AppiumElementLocator.java:76)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:95)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Cannot locate an element using By.chained({By.id: toggleStopStart})
>   For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time:
>   '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z' System info: host:
>   'bcnl-jmeunier.ad.netquest.com', ip:
>   'fe80:0:0:0:1cd6:7fc:4338:52b7%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
>   'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '10' Driver info:
>   driver.version: AndroidDriver     at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.ByChained.findElement(ByChained.java:72)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.ContentMappedBy.findElement(ContentMappedBy.java:36)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.lambda$0(AppiumElementLocator.java:96)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:150)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:248)
>     ... 31 more

*XML on Appium Inspector*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7b3M.png)

Comment: totally unclear. Provide appium server log with error you got + xml page source of screen where you are searching for element

Comment: done! let me know if you need further information

Comment: @Laura I think they mean to use this command during the test execution. 

https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/62700d3b1dc0edd985502cc1279747a782f3ee74/docs/en/commands/session/source.md

Screenshots are sometimes helpful but it is much easier to research stuff if we can copy and paste the exact text instead of typing it. 

Hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: Thanks I will check and I let you know. The only way I have now to interact with the mainActivity page after logging in the second time is opening and closing the notifications, for some reason it seems that appium is 'focused' on the notifications instead of the mainActivity page.